# Sending a fax in Access 2016 on Windows 10 (fax server uses Windows Server 2003)

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2003, fax, ms-access-2016

I have a legacy Access 2003 application that we have been running in Wondows 7.  I have decided to convert to Access 2016 so that it will continue to work in Windows 10 in case we ever need to replace one of our current Windows 7 machines and only Windows 10 is available.  It pretty much converted perfectly except for one of its features, sending faxes.

Our fax server is a Windows Server 2003 machine, and like I said I am running my application in Access 2016 on a Windows 10 machine.

This is my fax code:

```
Public Sub SendFax(RptName, faxNumber, faxName)

Dim FS As New FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServer
Dim FD As New FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocument
Dim strComputerName As String
Dim strFile As String

strComputerName = "server08"
strFile = "C:\Reports\test.snp"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, RptName, acFormatSNP, strFile, False
DoCmd.Close acReport, RptName

FS.Connect (strComputerName)
FD.Body = strFile

FD.CoverPageType = fcptNONE

FD.DocumentName = "Test"
FD.priority = fptHIGH

'FD.Recipients.Add USCanonicalPhone(faxNumber), faxName
FD.Recipients.Add faxNumber, faxName

FD.Submit(strComputerName)

End Sub
```

I have also tried using:

```
FD.ConnectedSubmit(FS)
```

in place of FD.Submit but either way the code blows up on that line.  I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147023741 (80070483)': Operation failed.
```

I did happen to stumble upon this web page that is outdated and references Vista, but I wonder if it holds true for Windows 10 as well: [Sending a Fax (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692936(v=vs.85).aspx)

I also tried implementing that JobID variable shown on that page into my code, but it still results in the same error.

I do see that there is a workaround mentioned on the web page about write permissions, but I don't know how to do this, plus I don't have a C:\ProgramData directory on my computer.

I also wonder if I would be able to set up a Windows 7 machine as a fax server and if that would solve the problem.  Of course our server is due for an upgrade given that its OS is 13 years old, would upgrading to Windows Server 2012 solve the problem?  Or should I wait for Windows Server 2016 to be released?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it a file association issue like here (same error number) https://www.interfax.net/en/dev/faxcomexlib/operation-failed.

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I found that the .snp format that I am using had been discontinued in Access 2010 and that Access now offers exporting to pdf.  So I set up my code to do that:  `strFile = "C:\Reports\test.snp"`  
`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, RptName, acFormatSNP, strFile, False`  
  
However, I'm still receiving the same error.  I don't understand how this can be a file association error as I have Acrobat installed on my computer and have no problem opening pdfs.  Is it possible that I would need to use a Microsoft pdf reader as opposed to Adobe?  
  
Thanks

Comment: Just realized, I don't have Acrobat, I'm using Microsoft Edge to open pdfs.

Comment: Just realized I cut and paste the wrong code  
`strFile = "C:\Reports\test.pdf"`  
`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, RptName, acFormatPDF, strFile, False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  The issue is most definitely a file association issue.  However it has nothing to do with Access 2016, or Windows Fax and Scan.  It has to deal with how you view PDF's.  (I assume the true would hold true for SNP files, but I only used SNP because Access 2003 didn't support export to PDF, no point in worrying about an outdated file format)

The issue is that the default viewer for pdf on a new install of Windows 10 is Microsoft Edge, and Microsoft Edge does not support printing to Fax.  To solve this problem you need to install Adobe Acrobat and set it as your default pdf viewer as it supports printing to faxes.  Once you do this you will have no problem sending PDF files to your fax server using code or printing PDF files to your fax server that you have open in Acrobat.

For those of you who are interested, here is my new code, not much has changed:

```
Public Sub SendFax(RptName, faxNumber, faxName)

Dim FS As New FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServer
Dim FD As New FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocument
Dim strComputerName As String
Dim strFile As String

strComputerName = "server08"
strFile = "C:\Reports\test.pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, RptName, acFormatPDF, strFile, False
DoCmd.Close acReport, RptName

FS.Connect strComputerName
FD.Body = strFile

FD.CoverPageType = fcptNONE

FD.DocumentName = "Test"
FD.priority = fptHIGH

FD.Recipients.Add faxNumber, faxName

FD.Submit (strComputerName)


End Sub
```

Of course you will need to be using "Microsoft Fax Service Extended COM Type Library" in References.

Comment: As a side note, you can export to RTF and it will fax no problem, however you will lose any images that you may have in your access report.  XLS could also work for faxing, but when I tried that the formatting in Excel was horrible, unreadable and spread across many pages.